# Add a ScriptMethod Helper to query PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add some simple helper methods to an existing PSCustomObject.
My goal is to replace something like this:

```
$Persons.Where{$_.FirstName -like "*Test*"}
```

With this:

```
$Persons.GetFirstName("Test")
```

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out a working ScriptMethod to use with add-member.
Here is my example code, along with all of the variations I have tried so far:

```
$Persons = [PSCustomObject]@()

$Person1 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    FirstName = 'John';
    LastName = 'Doe';
    Age = 27
    }
$Person2 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    FirstName = 'Test';
    LastName = 'Dummy';
    Age = 27
    }

$Persons += $Person1 
$Persons += $Person2 

$Persons
#FirstName LastName Age
#--------- -------- ---
#John      Doe       27
#Test      Dummy     27

#Get using a regular where method to confirm
$Persons.Where{$_.FirstName -like "*Test*"}
#FirstName LastName Age
#--------- -------- ---
#Test      Dummy     27

#Add the Helper Method GetFirstName
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where{$_.FirstName -like "$Args[0]"}}

#Check if the Test record is returned
$Persons.GetFullName("Test")

#Use this to remove the method for the next try
$Persons.PSObject.properties.remove('GetFirstName')

#Other Permutations I have tried
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where($this.FirstName -like "$($Args[0])")}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where({FirstName -like $Args[0]})}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where({FirstName -like $args(0)})}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where({FirstName -like "$Args[0]"})}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where({FirstName -like "$($Args[0])"})}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where({$this.FirstName -like $Args[0]})}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where({$this.FirstName -like "*$($Args[0])*"})}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where({$this.FirstName -eq $Args[0]})}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where({$_.FirstName -like $Args[0]})}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where({$_.FirstName -like "$($Args[0])"})}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where("FirstName -like ""$($Args[0])""")}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.where("$($_.FirstName) -like ""$($Args[0])""")}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.GetEnumerator().where{FirstName -like $Args[0]}}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.GetEnumerator().where{$this.FirstName -like $Args[0]}}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this.GetEnumerator().where{$_.FirstName -like $Args[0]}}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this | ?{$_.FirstName -like $Args[0]}}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this | ?({$_.FirstName -like $Args[0]})}
add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {$this | ?({$_.FirstName -like "$($Args[0])"})}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one `$Args` *per scope*, so `$Args` inside `.Where{ <in here> }` does not actually contain the input arguments to the script method - declare a named parameter instead and it'll work:

```
Add-Member -InputObject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {
  param([string]$fnArg)
  
  $this.Where{$_.FirstName -like $fnArg}
} -Force
```

Comment: You're awesome! Here is what I used (I quoted the param just in case):   ```add-member -inputobject $Persons -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetFirstName -Value {param([string]$fnArg); $this.where({$_.FirstName -Like "$fnArg"})}```

Comment: FWIW the `"` around `$fnArg` are doubly un-necessary here :-)

Comment: Even if the input contains spaces?

Comment: Guarding against spaces in input only makes sense _at the point of parsing input_ - in this context, on the other hand, it makes 0 difference. By "doubly" I mean: `$fnArg` is guaranteed to be a string (thanks to the `[string]` constraint in the parent scope), and `-like` _always_ takes a string as it's left-hand side operand, so even if the value of `$fnArg` _wasn't_ a string, it would automatically get converted to one :-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had actually just added a record with spaces in the name, and created two versions of the method, with and without, and you were absolutely right; the quotes made no difference.